# Utilidade do novo atributo global dropzone no HTML5?

Tags: html5

Quem sabe o objetivo do novo atributo global dropzone acrescentado no HTML5 e também gostaria de saber qual navegador suporta ele? Obrigada!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente quero deixar claro que o atributo `dropzone=""` ainda não é suportado por nenhum navegador, portanto por mais que tente usar ele não irá funcionar e ele ainda é experimental, ou seja pode ser que venha a se tornar padrão como também pode ser removido dos padrões do [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/dnd.html#the-dropzone-attribute) antes mesmo de qualquer navegador poder implementa-lo.

Qualquer elemento html poderá usar o atributo `dropzone` tendo mais de um valor ou não, esses valores devem ser separados por espaços, os valores suportados são:

- copy (exemplo: `<div dropzone="copy">`)

  Indica que o elemento irá aceitar o drop um itens do tipo especificado e irá resultar em uma cópia dos dados que foram arrastados.
- move (exemplo: `<div dropzone="move">`)

  Indica que o elemento irá aceitar o drop um itens do tipo especificado e os dados arrastados serão movidos para o novo local.
- link (exemplo: `<div dropzone="link">`)

  Indica que o elemento irá aceitar o drop um itens do tipo especificado e irá resultar em um link com os dados.
- Limitando por tipo de arquivo:

  ```
  <div dropzone="copy f:image/png f:image/gif f:image/jpeg">
  ```

  Isto irá limitar os dados do tipo imagem, png, jpeg e gif

Resumindo, até aonde entendi no w3.org, a ideia é que se mover uma imagem na área que tem o elemento você poderá limitar os tipos de arquivos ou outros elementos que poderão ser "dropados" no elemento com o atributo `dropzone=""`, esses arquivos ou elementos irão resultados em dados que provavelmente poderão ser lidos pela *DOM API* do Javascript do navegador, mas é como eu disse nenhum navegador suporta isso ainda e não sabemos se esse atributo será um dia lançado.

Todavia é possivel fazer dropzone sem o atributo, usando eventos como `ondrag` e `ondrop`, combinando com com a *File API* ou *DOM API* (vai depender do que você quer soltar nessa zona).

Comment: poderia escrever mais sobre o valor link? Obrigada!

Comment: @IngridFarabulini vou tentar, mas escrever sobre algo que ainda "não existe", ou melhor só existe no papel é um tanto quanto dificil, já que nao posso fazer testes pra afirmar o funcionamento.

Comment: Sim, você tem toda razão. Mesmo que não consiga, muito obrigada, explicação excelente e benéfica para toda a comunidade. Parabéns :)

Comment: Achei alguns "relatos" na internet, talvez amanhã consiga ler o texto todo (estão em inglês, sou um pouco lento pra ler e entender) e adicionar detalhes, mas parece que ao menos o primeiro que li também usa o termo "supostamente", quero dizer ainda não esta bem claro o objetivo, assim que adicionar mais detalhes te chamo via comentário.

Comment: Vale dizer que isso faz sentido quando se tratar de drop do OS para o browser, por isso existe a definição dos mime-types e do tipo de operação.  Por exemplo: ao se arrastar um ícone do PC para o _browser_ em um "move" significa deletar ele do PC se a operação for bem sucedida. Arrastar para um "copy" significa um upload sem apagar o original. Arrastar um "link" significa enviar apenas a referência, sem upar nada (estou falando do funcionamento teórico, quanto ao que vai acontecer de verdade, pode não fazer nenhum sentido, como outras muitas decisões do W3 que são contraintuitivas).